# Disk UUID from blkid output disappears

Tags: linux, mount, uuid, device-mapper, block-device

I'm experiencing a weird situation on RHEL-7. I create a device mapper (crypt) over a disk partition and then copy data (bytes) from disk partition to mapper. The blkid output has two entries for the UUID - one for disk partition and other for mapper. The UUID under /dev/disk/by-uuid points to mapper as it was overwritten.

**blkid output:**

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="1e762c4a-0b12-40fc-9f53-a825016211a0" TYPE="ext4"

/dev/mapper/my_mapper: UUID="1e762c4a-0b12-40fc-9f53-a825016211a0" TYPE="ext4"
```

**/dev/disk/by-uuid output:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 31 10:24 1e762c4a-0b12-40fc-9f53-a825016211a0 -> ../../dm-4
```

Now, I again copy data (bytes) from mapper to disk partition and close the mapper. The UUID under /dev/disk/by-uuid points to disk partition and blkid output shows UUID for the disk partition.

**blkid output:**

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="1e762c4a-0b12-40fc-9f53-a825016211a0" TYPE="ext4"
```

**/dev/disk/by-uuid output:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 31 10:24 1e762c4a-0b12-40fc-9f53-a825016211a0 -> ../../sdc1
```

but, once I try to mount the disk partition, I get the error:

```
mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/sdc1 /mnt/plainDisk
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1.
```

and then the disk disappears from blkid output. The /dev/disk/by-uuid is still present with correct UUID and lsblk shows the disk.

I'm using `blockdev --getsize64` to get the size of disk in bytes and then copying all these bytes.

Any inputs or pointers are appreciated. I'm not facing this issue on RHEL-6 though.

**Additional Info:**

1. I use `fsync` over /dev/sdc1 file descriptor once all data is copied.
2. I verified the dumpe2fs output when /dev/sdc1 was present after second copy. It matched the original values. However, once the entry was removed, the dumpe2fs gives the error:

*dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)*

*dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1*

*Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.*

Comment: What does `dmesg` say?

Comment: There was no error in dmesg other than "wrong fs type".

Comment: `VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that while copying data back from `my_mapper` to `sdc1`, `my_mapper` was still ***mounted***. This somehow affected the superblock on the device. I ran `dumpe2fs` and checked that there are some entries related to *mount* in the superblock.

**unmounting the mapper before copying the data resolved the issue.**